# How to attach a callback to a custom confirmation dialog in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am creating a custom confirmation dialog in Google App Maker and would like the Confirm button to call a passed-in function.  I don't see an "onclick" event in the button widget.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
function confirmationDialog(msg, confirmFunction)
{
  var desc = app.pageFragments.ConfirmationDialog.descendants;
  var label = desc.Label;
  var confirmButton = desc.Confirm;

  label.text = msg;
  confirmButton.onClick = confirmFunction;  // does not work

  app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.ConfirmationDialog);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: well, based on your code, id say..... wait, you didn't provide any code. how are we supposed to fix your code when you didn;'t give us any?

Comment: I did not add code as I could not find any event on the widget to try.  But I have added what would be nice to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be great if this was a bit easier, but the best bet is to use Custom Properties (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/viewfragments).

You can set up a custom property of type "Dynamic" and call it anything, take "onConfirmCallback", for example. Then you can set the function on that custom property:

Code to invoke dialog:

```
app.pageFragments.ConfirmationDialog.properties.onConfirmCallback = function(param) {
  alert(param); 
};
app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.ConfirmationDialog);
```

And then in the onClick for the close button:

```
app.pageFragments.ConfirmationDialog.properties.onConfirmCallback("hi");
app.closeDialog();
```

Also note that there are slightly better ways to set up labels than in your example, also using custom properties.

Create custom properties for any widget properties you want to customize, and then bind those custom properties (@properties.propertyName) to the widget property. For example you might have a confirmText property, with the confirm buttons text property boudn to @properties.confirmText.

Then when you invoke your dialog, you can just set those custom properties. Quick modification of your example code using properties for everything:

```
function confirmationDialog(msg, confirmFunction)
{
  var properties = app.pageFragments.ConfirmationDialog.properties;
  properties.text = msg;
  properties.confirmCallback = confirmFunction;

  app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.ConfirmationDialog);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for idea to use properties, was able to get it working.  Code is nice and clean now!

Answer (score 0):

For my confirmation dialogs, I just set the onclick of the OK button before I show the dialog (everything is in one place, which is easier for the dummy (me) who will have to maintain it in six months:

```
  var dialog=app.pages.ConfirmationDialog;
  dialog.descendants.message.text='Are you sure...?'
  dialog.descendants.btnOk.getElement().onclick=function(){
      //do something here
      app.closeDialog();
    });
  };
  app.showDialog(dialog);
}
```