# How to display DropDown options using values from two fields

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have a DropDown that shows a list of indicators. I want it to display as options values from two fields *IndicatorCode* and *IndicatorName*, ideally it should also have a ": " or any other character in between. As bindings for the DropDown I have:

*Options*: **@datasource.items**,

*Value*: **@datasource.item**

*Names*: I tried the following but it does not work well **@datasources.MyDatasource.items..IndicatorCode+':'+@datasources.MyDatasource.items..IndicatorName**

Comment: Bind a function instead of values. Pass these two values to that function and from the function return the desired value. Normal JavaScript stuff

Comment: You could either bind a client based function as Darpan pointed out. Or as explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638663/how-to-attach-a-callback-to-a-custom-confirmation-dialog-in-google-app-maker) you can declare a custom property that hands over the options as merged.

Comment: Thank you Darpan! I followed your advice and it worked very well. Thanks Johan for the link, very useful I will use it in a custom property. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have `Person` model/datasource and you need to show in the `Dropdown` user's `Display Name` (`First Name + Last Name`). In this case binding for the `names` Dropdown's property will look like this:

```javascript
getPeopleDisplayNames(@datasources.People.items)
```

and here is client script for the `getPeopleDisplayNames` function

```javascript
function getPeopleDisplayNames(personList) {
  if (personList) {
    return personList.map(function (person) {
      return person.FirstName + ' ' + person.LastName;
    });
  }

  return personList;
}
```

Here are couple related topics from Google Groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appmaker-users/0zGl85fEU4Y/discussion
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appmaker-users/Pg6cyZBIOMk/discussion

Comment: Thanks a lot Pavel!  I used a function that receives two lists as I am using it in different pages with different models. I like your proposed solution better. Very useful.