# Showing confirmation popup on top of a dialog

Tags: google-app-maker

I am displaying a page by below script

```
 app.showDialog(app.pages.test);
```

on the test page, which has an update button to invoke a popup (Update confirmation with Yes and No button), Problem is when the update button is clicked confirmation popup shows behind the dialog box. I tried with below css

```
 .runtimeRoot .app-PopupOverlay {
    z-index: 20;
 }
```

Using the above css, popup comes on top, but not clickable. Is there a way fix this?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to fix this at the moment due to the priorities of those type of widgets/pages within the App Maker hierarchy. The way I have solved this problem is to temporarily close the dialog and open the popup, then when clicking a button in the popup to close the popup and then open the dialog back up.

Comment: I was able to get this done by fragmented page. Followed below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638663/how-to-attach-a-callback-to-a-custom-confirmation-dialog-in-google-app-maker